# Least Recently Used Cache Daily Coding Practice

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, cache

I have the following challenge problem for which I was able to get a solution working, but not in \$O(1)\$ time as the problem asks for.  Could someone point me in the right direction to optimize this? I am also open to other criticisms of my coding style.

QUESTION:

> Implement an LRU (Least Recently Used) cache. It should be able to be initialized with a cache size n, and contain the following methods:
>
> - `set(key, value)`: sets key to value. If there are already n items in the cache and we are adding a new item, then it should also remove the least recently used item.
> - `get(key)`: gets the value at key. If no such key exists, return null.
>
> Each operation should run in \$O(1)\$ time.

CODE:

```
class LRUcache():

    def __init__(self,n):
        self.vals = dict()
        self.max_size = n

    def set(self,key,value):
        if key in self.vals:
            del self.vals[key]
            self.vals[key] = value
        else:
            if(len(self.vals) < self.max_size):
                self.vals[key] = value
            else:
                del self.vals[list(self.vals)[0]]
                self.vals[key] = value

    def get(self,key):
        if key in self.vals:
            tempval = self.vals[key]
            del self.vals[key]
            self.vals[key] = tempval
            return self.vals[key]
        return None
```

Comment: I think that the CS textbooks simplify things, when they claim that hash tables are O(1) containers. The never are. The real hash tables are always O(n),  but with a very small C (the implicit mutiplier in the Big O notation). In other words, I do not think you can improve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first look, it seems like it should be O(1), except for the `list(self.vals())[0]`.
Try iterating over the keys instead:

```
def set(self,key,value):
    if key in self.vals:
        del self.vals[key]
        self.vals[key] = value
    else:
        if(len(self.vals) < self.max_size):
            self.vals[key] = value
        else:
            del self.vals[next(iter(self.vals))]    #### changed
            self.vals[key] = value
```

Comment: This is just what I was missing, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your code reads very much like you have written some Java and are trying to translate it to Python. You need to "drink the Kool-Aid" and start embracing idiomatic Python, instead.

First, start by noting that storing `None` as a value is a legitimate thing to do in Python. So the idea of returning `None` to mean "no key found" is weak. A better approach would be to `raise` an exception -- probably a `KeyError`.

However, since it's part of your problem statement, we can ignore that issue (except to note that your problem statement likely came from Java or C++ or someplace like that).

In your `set()` method:

```
def set(self,key,value):
    if key in self.vals:
        del self.vals[key]
        self.vals[key] = value
    else:
        if(len(self.vals) < self.max_size):
            self.vals[key] = value
        else:
            del self.vals[list(self.vals)[0]]
            self.vals[key] = value
```

You can overwrite items in a dictionary directly. Just assign to them:

```
if key in self.vals:
    self.vals[key] = value
```

And your missing-key code is redundant. You assign value in both branches of the `if/else` statement. Just refactor the assignment down:

```
if len(self.vals) >= self.max_size:
    del self.vals[list(self.vals)[0]]

self.vals[key] = value
```

Once you do that, you realize that the assignment is *also* present in the upper (key-found) condition, and you can refactor it again:

```
def set(self, key, value):
    vals = self.vals
    if key in vals and len(vals) >= self.max_size:
        del vals[list(vals)[0]]
    vals[key] = value
```

In your `get()` method:

You are doing things pretty much spot-on, here, but you are depending on dictionaries to preserve insertion order. That is a somewhat new feature in python (added as an implementation detail in 3.6, and guaranteed in 3.7) that won't work in 3.5. You should at least comment this, and probably should add code at the top of your module to verify the version of python.

**On the other hand:** there is a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) in the standard library that has been around for a while, and which even includes an example of building an LRU cache in the documentation. Just sayin'. ;-)

Comment: I thing you are wrong. Deleting and adding a key-value pair is not going to work the same way as  assigning a value by a key. The whole point of doing the way OP did is to alter the internal order of the map. In your case, I think,  it won' happen.

Comment: thanks for the tips! My code looks much nicer now!